# Fetching data through Query Component inside react's useEffect

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using `react-apollo`'s `<Query>` component inside my function component to fetch data from Apollo server graphql microservice. I want to update the state of my component using `useEffect` hook and `Query` component.

I tried using `Query` component within `useEffect` function, but the request is not going without giving any error

```
const foo = () => {
   const [bar, setBar] = useState([]);
   const fetchBars = () => (<Query query={fetchQuery}>{({loading, error, data}) => {
         if(!loading) console.log(data);
      }})
   useEffect(() => {
    fetchBars();
   }, []);
}
```

Ideally, it should call graphql api and fetch the data but console is not coming up. I tried using `axios` library instead of `Query` component and the request is going through, but I don't want to introduce new stuff to do same thing.

Comment: edited the code, it was a typo

Comment: I'm pretty new to Apollo stuff as well, but maybe it's a problem that you're never using the `<Query>` component anywhere, just declaring it?  Did you mean to do something like use `setBar(<Query ... />` and then render that in the return of this functional component?

Comment: ultimately yes, i would be calling `setBar` function, but even if without that, `fetchBars` function should get called

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example with stackoverflow’s embedded code please?

Comment: AFAIK `if(!loading) console.log(data);` never gets executed because you are not rendering the `<Query />` component. You're just defining it.

Comment: @MarioSubotic that’s what I thought too...

Comment: So how could I render `<Query>` component within `fetchBars`